# RouteTable Redirect for SiteMap

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, sitemap

I've seen this code a ton on this site, but I can't seem to get it to work.  When I navigate to www.mysite.com/sitemap.xml it gives me a 404 error.  Here is my code for the `RouteTable` setup:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.Clear();
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Sitemap",
            "sitemap.xml",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "SiteMap" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Here is the Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

Would someone please point out what I've done wrong?  It looks like the examples given in questions such as [C# mvc3 redirect sitemap.xml to controller action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687471/c-sharp-mvc3-redirect-sitemap-xml-to-controller-action).

Comment: Put it in debug and check where it's actually trying to route to..

Comment: I didn't know you could debug the routing.  Where would I put the break point?

Comment: I mean the website.. is it showing a 404 error or the .NET 'Cannot find view/route' error page?

Comment: Detailed Error Information:
Module    IIS Web Core
Notification    MapRequestHandler
Handler    StaticFile
Error Code    0x80070002
Requested URL    http://localhost:8295/sitemap.xml
Physical Path    C:\Users\Dev\Documents\Dev\Site\sitemap.xml
Logon Method    Anonymous
Logon User    Anonymous
Request Tracing Directory    C:\Users\Dev\Documents\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles\SITE   Is this the information you needed?

Comment: It's definitely a 404 error.  "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Comment: I noticed the handler is listed as StaticFile, is that the issue?

Comment: In a test, I removed the StaticFile handler, now it just says "Not yet determined" for the handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more trial and error playing with handlers, I was able to get it working.  It turns out that `StaticFile` handler was indeed the issue.  I was able to fix it by adding the following to my web.config file:

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit_XML" path="*.xml" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit_XML" path="*.xml" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0_XML" path="*.xml" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this shorter version found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8846619/1184603)

```
<handlers>
<add name="xml-file-handler" path="*.xml" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" verb="*" />
</handlers>
```